# Save checked values on page refresh?

Tags: php, forms, session

Ive saved form data with ajax and php, reusing the data from the database.

However the way I am approaching this is different, there is no database, so some insight would be great.

I am emailing form data, all the data is just simple checkboxes, the values are either `0` or `1`. When the user refreshes the page id like to keep the checked values.

I guess without a database I would need to use cookies, and the only way to avoid cookies would be ajax and a database (strictly my logic, not sure if true), this is why I am asking, I just want a simple solution.

**Form snippet:**

```
<input name="sharks" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="sharks" type="checkbox" value="1" id="sharks" '.$VALUE ? ' checked="checked"' : ''.'>
```

The php part of that input is shaky, Id like to question whether the value is 0 or 1, if its 1 then its checked if its 0 then empty.

Getting it from the database would be easier but not so sure since there is no database, Im guessing cookies would come into place.

Sorry if this last part is shaky but im a little unsure and dont know where to look.

**Using Sessions:**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if(isset($_POST['personalization_result'])) {   
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['personalization_result']; } 
   else {
    $_SESSION['value'] = '';  
   }
}
```

**Form**

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" id="question-form"> 

  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">

       <?php 

             if ($_SESSION['value'] == 1) {
              $checked = 'checked="checked"'; } 

        ?>  

 <li>   
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden"   value="0">
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_0" <?php $checked ?> >
 </li>

 <li>   
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_1]" type="hidden"   value="0">
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_1]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_1" <?php $checked ?> >
 </li>

 <li>   
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_2]" type="hidden"   value="0">
 <input name="personalization_result[memory_2]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_2" <?php $checked ?> >
 </li>
```

Comment: You could always save the `$_POST` in a `$_SESSION` something like at the top of your page `$_SESSION['vals'] = $_POST;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code stores the data in a session:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['sharks']))
    {
        $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['sharks'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['value'] = '';
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php
print '<input name="sharks" type="checkbox" value="1" id="sharks" ';
if ($_SESSION['value'] == 1)
{
    print ' checked="checked"';
}

print ">";
?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Worked for me, keeping the checkbox checked after I closed and opened the browser again. After some testing I added a rather complex `if` to avoid the undefined variable notice. Now the set part seems robust.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping someone would post a snippet... that is what I needed (to write the if isset submit) that will handle all the data nicely, I know you would do that with the database, I now know you can also write sessions inside that isset, this is great thanks

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Physically all session data is stored in a simple database on disk.

Comment: I made some modifications to fit my code, it's not working, im posting what I have in the OP hopefully you can see what I am doing wrong, but basically I am trying to store the `if ($_SESSION)` in a variable.

Comment: I ran the code your way and I got it to work, but fitting in with my code id like to store the if value = 1 result in a variable, I dont want to run an if statement for each input field

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Create an array of names and loop through the array, checking `if(isset($_POST[$var_name]))` in the loop. Thus, you can check and set every variable to session.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use session or cookie. Basically you will access using `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION`. I would rather say that this is easier than using a database.

For cookies have a look at `setcookie` (http://www.php.net/setcookie)

For sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Yeah I totally bet it's easier than a database, but since I've never approached saving data with cookies, and have database experience obviously based on what I know the database method would be easier, but I am going to read up on those links and wrap my head around it, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I guarantee it is easy. For cookies use `setcookie` and retrieve using `$_COOKIE`. For sessions you will use `session_start()` and use `$_SESSION` to set/get values. I prefer using sessions rather than cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I would use local storage or session storage, this is a client side memory storage location that persists even if the page is refreshed, it is integrated into html5.

Here is a nice tutorial about it:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Ok ill take a look, I keep hearing about localstorage it seems quite popular I came across some info using local storage, by just glancing at it, seemed a bit much, again I just glanced at it, let me read up on the w3schools

Comment: It's really quite easy, it's basically just an associative array variable that is pre-defined and remembered between refreshes.  It is kind of like php's $_SESSION variable except it is client side only.

Comment: [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) has a much better explanation of HTML5 storage.

Comment: Yeah and thats another thing I noticed, and realize why its quite popular its the future of the web and correlates with new technology like HTML5, so it's definitely a must have skill to pickup.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Persist checkboxes 1</title>
        <script>
            window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='jquery-.1.1.js'><\/script>");
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#me').click(function()
                {

                    var seloption = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
                    if (seloption.length > 0)
                    {
                        var abc = seloption.length + "checked \n";
                        //alert(abc);
                        i = 0;
                        seloption.each(function()
                        {
                            abc = abc + $(this).text(seloption[i]) + "<br>";
                        }

                        );
                        $('#msg').html(abc);
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option4">Option 4</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option5">Option 5</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option6">Option 6</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option6">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option7">Option 7</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option7">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option8">Option 8</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option8">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="option9">Option 9</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option9">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="me">Submit</button>
        <div id="msg">



        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
                var checkboxValues = {};
                $(":checkbox").each(function() {

                    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;

                });
                $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, {expires: 1, path: '/'});


            });

            function repopulateCheckboxes() {
                var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');

                if (checkboxValues) {
                    Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
                        var checked = checkboxValues[element];
                        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);

                    });
                }
            }

            $.cookie.json = true;

            repopulateCheckboxes();
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: "code only" answers are close to worthless; especially when talking about quite some amount of code. You really want to put in some explanations what exactly your solution is doing!

Comment: yeah what you need to know init